# Show that $F$ is smooth $\Leftrightarrow$ $f\circ F$ is smooth for all $f\in C^\infty(N)$

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

> Let $F:M\to N$ be a map between smooth manifolds $M$ and $N$.
>
> Show that $F$ is smooth $\Leftrightarrow$ $f\circ F:M\to\mathbb{R}$ is smooth for all $f\in C^\infty(N)$.

One of the implications are obvious. To the other one I can transform the problem in a $\mathbb{R}^n$ calculus problem, but I don't know if it is the easier way to solve it and I don't know if this new problem is easily solvable.

Let's assume that $f\circ F$ is smooth for all $f\in C^\infty(N)$. Since $M$ and $N$ are manifolds, for some $p\in M$, let $(U,\phi)$ and $(V,\psi)$ be charts of $M$ and $N$ resp. with $p\in M$ and $F(p)\in V$. So,
$$(f\circ\psi^{-1})\circ(\psi\circ F\circ\phi^{-1}) =(f\circ F)\circ \phi^{-1}:\phi(U)\subset\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}$$
is smooth and if we define $g=f\circ\psi^{-1}:\psi(V)\to\mathbb{R}$ and $G=\psi\circ F\circ\phi^{-1}:\phi(U)\subset\mathbb{R}^m\to\psi(V)\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ we get the following:

> $g\circ G:\phi(U)\to\mathbb{R}$ is smooth for all $g\in C^\infty(\psi(V))$ $\Rightarrow$ $G$ is smooth.

Can you give me some help?

Comment: What if you choose f= the identity function on N

Comment: $f$ must to be a real-valued function.

Comment: Ahh my bad I've not read the question properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\textbf{Hint:}$
A map $\tilde F:\tilde U\to \tilde V$ between open subsets of euclidean spaces is smooth iff the maps $\text{pr}_i\circ\tilde F$ are smooth, where $\text{pr}_i$ is the projecion onto the $i$-th coordinate.